# Upstart - Job starts but then stops immediately

Tags: php, daemon, centos6, upstart

I am trying to set up an upstart job but for some reason it stops immediately after starting

I'm on Cents 6.5 btw

here are my files:

**/ect/init/test-daemon.conf**

```
start on startup
stop on shutdown
respawn

script
    sudo -u root php -f /usr/share/test_daemon.php
end script
```

**/usr/share/test-daemon.php**

```
<?php

    // The worker will execute every X seconds:
    $seconds = 2;

    // We work out the micro seconds ready to be used by the 'usleep' function.
    $micro = $seconds * 1000000;

    while(true){

        // Now before we 'cycle' again, we'll sleep for a bit...
        usleep($micro);
    }
```

I have then got this file: (which I found on a forum that logs events)

**/tmp/log.file**

```
debug/ (/dev/fd/10):19735:Fri Jul 25 11:52:40 AST 2014:Job
test-daemon/ starting. Environment was: TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/ JOB=test-daemon
SHLVL=1
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=starting
UPSTART_JOB=debug
INSTANCE=
_=/usr/bin/env

debug/ (/dev/fd/9):19775:Fri Jul 25 11:52:41 AST 2014:Job test-daemon/ stopping. Environment was:
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
JOB=test-daemon
RESULT=ok
SHLVL=1
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=stopping
UPSTART_JOB=debug
INSTANCE=
_=/usr/bin/env

debug/ (/dev/fd/9):19779:Fri Jul 25 11:52:41 AST 2014:Job test-daemon/ stopping. Environment was:
TERM=linux
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
JOB=test-daemon
RESULT=failed
SHLVL=1
PROCESS=respawn
UPSTART_INSTANCE=
UPSTART_EVENTS=stopping
UPSTART_JOB=debug
INSTANCE=
_=/usr/bin/env
```

in the log file, I get more debug information but its basically the above repeated a few times.

I get this from running `start test-daemon` which outputs `test-daemon start/running, process 20600`

I know the test-daemon.php doesn't actually do anything...at the moment I just need to get the actual job running, once thats fixed ill drop in my code

So from the above...is there anything I am doing wrong? as the job should only stop if I run `stop test-daemon`  right?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather post a comment but with the low reputation limit I can not.
I am not familiar with this distro flavor but did you try to use nohup ?
Like this:

`nohup php -f /usr/share/test_daemon.php &`

It could be possible that detaching your command from the service process kills it.

Comment: Hi @NaeiinDus, thanks for you reply, this is what I get when i put in your cmd:

[1] 11512
root@server [~]# nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'

what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, i checked the nohup.out file... but it is empty?

Comment: The default behavior of nohup is to redirect all the output the command generated to a file (nohup.out). It is the same as "nohup [cmd] > ./nohup.out`
Since nohup is used to create a background program, it also ignores all possible input (so you cannot send it information using STDIN).

It is normal that your file is empty, your script doesn't output a thing :)
Try adding a dummy echo and you should see something.